# Pulling data from a web page into excel

Tags: excel, database, html

Assume a site like https://www.wood-database.com/wood-finder/ (our working example). Each page of it has data on a wood species. Assuming we need to sort the woods by a ratio of its data, for example hardness/weight, the site's tools aren't very useful.

What *would be* useful, though, is passing that data into an excel, which could trivially calculate the ratio and sort.

What ways are there to automatically fill that sheet out? What other tools besides excel could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at python, it's perfectly fit for the job. You could use the request library together with beatifulsoup to begin with, then load all data into a Pandas Dataframe and simply export it to excel (standard funtionality of Pandas).

If you really want to scrape the site thoroughly, you could consider using Scrapy (https://scrapy.org/)

Comment: That's a neat idea! However, I was hoping for somwthing more short-term, since this is likely an one-time task. Something like batch files and reggex is where my mind went initially, but I'm not too good with either.